# addView android force close

Tags: android, dynamic, view

The following is my code.I'm trying to add add a view to the LinearLayout *activity_dynamic* that I've already created

```
public void onClick(View v)

   { 

    switch(v.getId()) {
   case R.id.add:

       Log.v("test","as");
       TextView t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.a_text_view);
       LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)     findViewById(R.layout.activity_dynamic);
       layout .addView(t, 1);           






   }
}
```

Code for activity_dynamic.xml  is :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:text="Add View" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Everything works fine , but when I press Add View , i get a force close

The LogCat Readings are as follows :

```
03-05 18:05:54.639: E/Trace(10003): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-05 18:05:55.169: D/libEGL(10003): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
03-05 18:05:55.179: D/libEGL(10003): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
03-05 18:05:55.179: D/libEGL(10003): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
03-05 18:05:55.189: I/Adreno200-EGL(10003): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:294>: EGL 1.4     QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB.04.01.01.00.036_msm8960_JB_CL2644550_release_AU (CL2644550)
03-05 18:05:55.189: I/Adreno200-EGL(10003): Build Date: 07/31/12 Tue
03-05 18:05:55.189: I/Adreno200-EGL(10003): Local Branch: 
03-05 18:05:55.189: I/Adreno200-EGL(10003): Remote Branch: quic/master
03-05 18:05:55.189: I/Adreno200-EGL(10003): Local Patches: NONE
03-05 18:05:55.189: I/Adreno200-EGL(10003): Reconstruct Branch:     AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB.04.01.01.00.036 +  NOTHING
03-05 18:05:55.319: D/OpenGLRenderer(10003): Enabling debug mode 0
03-05 18:05:59.624: V/test(10003): as
03-05 18:05:59.624: D/AndroidRuntime(10003): Shutting down VM
03-05 18:05:59.624: W/dalvikvm(10003): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d5e300)
03-05 18:05:59.874: E/AndroidRuntime(10003): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 18:05:59.874: E/AndroidRuntime(10003): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 18:05:59.874: E/AndroidRuntime(10003):    at com.example.database.Dynamic.onClick(Dynamic.java:52)
03-05 18:05:59.874: E/AndroidRuntime(10003):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
03-05 18:05:59.874: E/AndroidRuntime(10003):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
03-05 18:05:59.874: E/AndroidRuntime(10003):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-05 18:05:59.874: E/AndroidRuntime(10003):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-05 18:05:59.874: E/AndroidRuntime(10003):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 18:05:59.874: E/AndroidRuntime(10003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4978)
03-05 18:05:59.874: E/AndroidRuntime(10003):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 18:05:59.874: E/AndroidRuntime(10003):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 18:05:59.874: E/AndroidRuntime(10003):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
03-05 18:05:59.874: E/AndroidRuntime(10003):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
03-05 18:05:59.874: E/AndroidRuntime(10003):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Why is this happening ?

I appreciate your help , thanks :D

Comment: in which layout u have a_text_view TextView ? and activity_dynamic layout is your current Activity layout ?

Comment: Post your complete java code. And what is line no 52

Comment: Yes , activity_dynamic is mycurrent activity layout.

Line 52 is:  layout .addView(t, 1);

Comment: @Anant you can't add t to the layout because it already has a parent. What are you trying to achieve? post complete code.

Comment: @Pragnani - I'm trying to add views dynamically

Comment: @Anant post your Dynamic.java class or it is difficult to identify your problem

Comment: @Pragnani Here it is http://pastebin.com/VQhErzdY

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25618/discussion-between-pragnani-and-anant)

Comment: @Anant I have posted the answer check it...That will solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code what is wrong is

```
  layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_dynamic);
```

you are getting the LinearLayout with layout, You should get it using `R.id.yourlayoutid`

should be like

```
 layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourlayoutid);
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

```
 TextView t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.a_text_view);
```

You can't add text view as it already has a parent you need to

1. Delete the textview from the xml layout and create the textview dynamically and add this to linearlayout.

do like this

```
TextView t=new TextView(this);
layout.addView(t);
```

have you added break in your switch case statement

```
 case R.id.add:

           Log.v("test","as");
            TextView t=new TextView(this);
          layout.addView(t);

 break;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.a_text_view);
```

You can't add text view as it already has a parent, remove from xml layout.
and also you need to write below lines in uiThread `(onCreate())`.

```
 LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) 
findViewById(R.layout.activity_dynamic);
```

and then,

```
 public void onClick(View v) { 
switch(v.getId()) { 
   case R.id.add:

   Log.v("test","as");
   TextView t=new TextView(yourActivity.this); 
   layout.addView(t,1);          } }
```

EDIT : 
Complete code will look like this,

```
LinearLayout layout;
Button btnAdd;
TextView txtView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_dynamic);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) { 
       case R.id.add:
       Log.v("test","as");
       TextView t=new TextView(this); 
       layout.addView(t,1);          
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: this gives me a force close , the activity won't even open up

Answer (score 0):

add `this.addview(layout)` in code